# Short for an if condition with logical OR operator?

Tags: c++

How to shorten the length of the condition if it's comparing the same variable to multiple values?

I've used the logical OR operator but it's too long and i have a lot of condition.

`if (input=='1' || input=='3' || input=='7')`

I expect the condition to be shorter because I have so many conditions but within the same variable.

Comment: It's too long for what ?

Comment: You could put them into a set then check for membership in the set. That may be cleaner.

Comment: If you expect a shorter form of the test, then your expectations will remain unfilled.  There is not an equivalent shorter form in C++.

Comment: @Carcigenicate - it may be cleaner, and even more amenable to extension.   But having to `#include <set>`, create and populate the set, and then check if the value is in the set is unlikely to be "shorter" by the OP's criteria (which appears to be shortest possible code for this single test).

Comment: @Peter It depends if they simply want that line/shorter, or just less code in general. If it's the former, with a set, you can easily define it elsewhere and use it as necessary. You could use a plain function too. If it's the latter, ya, you're right. It's unlikely to be an improvement.

Comment: Have you used the `switch` statement, before?

Comment: @Carcigenicate, an `unordered_set` would be a better choice.

Comment: Remember that if you crush code too much it becomes hard to read.

Comment: how long is "too long"? your example is quite short and readable

Comment: Your condition looks perfect. To make it better it needs context. Show us how you use it in combination with "_i have so many conditions_". The "_within the same variable_" is vague at best.

Answer (score 1):

You could write your `if` statement like this:

```
if (strchr("137", input))
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [switch](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch) statement for comparing integers or characters in C++.

Allow fall through for multiple cases.

For your example:

```
switch (input) {
    case '1':
    case '3':
    case '7':
        do_something();
        break;
    default:
        do_something_else();
        break;
}
```

The compiler will (probably) generate code that uses a jump table, avoiding the need to test explicitly against each value. The values in the case labels have to be constant.

Comment: If you are trying to link to external documentation: please don't link to unknown, sketchy websites. Nowadays [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com) is a go-to documentation for C++. So, for switch statement, [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch) would be the link, to proper documentation.

Comment: "_Allow fall through for multiple cases_" may deserve an explanation.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Noted. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the canonical way is creating a set and check it with `find()`

```
std::set<int> s;
s.insert(...) 
if (s.find(input) != s.end()) {
   //do stuff
}
```

This will shorten the if condition, but you'll have to fill the set first. Depending on the situation, it could be more readeable with a long if.

Comment: An unordered set would be a better choice.

Comment: @SidS for the OP purposes, a set or an unordered set would make no difference. If he’s going to check thousands of conditions, then your point is absolutely valid.

Comment: My point is that there is no need to sort data when you don't need to access elements in sorted order.

Comment: in this case `std::strchr` is probably enough.

Comment: @SidS yeah, I got your point, but in this case for 3 conditions there is no time difference between a set and unordered_set

Comment: @Norhther But, how do you know, that the real code, the OP is using, has, at most, 3 conditions? OP even stated "i have so much condition but within the same variable." in his question.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I think OP is asking for the conditions of the example he gave. But as I said, unless the OP has thousands of conditions there would be no difference in performance. Otherwise I’m with you, O(1) is going to make a real impact inserting and searching

Comment: If this is supposed to be an answer - connect it with OP:s question. How is he/she to connect the dots with this only?

Comment: 1) "_I think OP is asking for the conditions of the example he gave._" Why? It was clear that you think like this already, but you didn't answer my question ("how do you know, that"). The intention, and issue, is just as well explained with `3` condition `if` statement as `1000` condition `if` statement. 2) "_But as I said, unless the OP has thousands of conditions there would be no difference in performance._" Why does it hurt, to learn good habits from a get-go?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I mean how do you even know if it's an integer, this solution doesn't work as is

Comment: @LTPCGO "_I mean how do you even know if it's an integer_" I don't. Where, did I say, that I knew that. The entire point of my comments was - we don't know exact use case, because what was provided, was minimal example.

Answer (score 0):

Solution really depend on what checks you need and what constrains you have. You can check against set of values. You can use 'switch' if values are integer or enum and may result in different actions.

Or you may devise function that matches your check, write it as a inline function, or use some numerological magic. For your example uf you have to check if character is an odd digit:

```
if(std::isdigit(input) && ((input - '0') & 1) )
```

Be creative, but not too creative... if expression inside if is too complex, it becomes unreadable and a source of mistakes. In such case better to define a function, which would have a comment a good name.

Answer (score 0):

This answer gives you the ability to do the same search for something beyond an integer:

```
Foo some_array[n];
// Populate array here...
// If the object is not in the array, std::find returns the end of the range
if( std::find(std::begin(some_array), std::end(some_array), item_to_look_for) != std::end(some_array) ) {
    //found!
} else {
    //not found
}
```